# find bold text in excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

How to find bold text inside cells of Excel sheet? I'm using C#, OLEDB and ADO.NET for reading xls file, but I don't resolve how to resolve my task. Do I need to use Iterop.Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will need Interop.Excel

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

int FindFirstBold(Range cell)
{    
    for (int index = 1; index <= cell.Text.ToString().Length; index++)
    {
        Characters ch = cell.get_Characters(index, 1);
        bool bold = (bool) ch.Font.Bold;
        if(bold) return index;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! you helped me a lot. i can check now the whole cell text for boldness
Range test;
bool isBold = (bool)test.Font.Bold;

Comment: nice answer, I don't suppose you know much about detecting cells containing pivot tables using interop? I have asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623752/detect-pivot-table-in-microsoft-excel-using-interop-c-sharp