# How to check bold style in wrapText in excel file using c#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

How to check bold text inside cells of Excel sheet? I'm using C#, Epplus for  reading excel file, but I don't resolve how to resolve my task.So can you please tell me how ti resolved it?

Input: In cell of excel

```
  •   On Command 
  •   **On proceeds**
  •   Exclude guidance
  •   **On Demand**
```

Output:

```
•  **On proceeds**
•   **On Demand**
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122741/find-bold-text-in-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp Use search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find bold text in excel sheet using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122741/find-bold-text-in-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @KalanaDemel - No duplicate, `Interop.Excel != EPPLus`. The question is **clearly** tagged with `epplus`.

Comment: thanks @kuujinbo...its working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're really after, but assuming you have a spreadsheet like this:

[image]

Where bold text is in red, this extracts all cells with bold text:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
{
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
    {
        var cell = sheet.Cells[1, i];
        if (cell.IsRichText) {
            foreach (var element in cell.RichText)
            {
                if (element.Bold) 
                    Console.WriteLine("Rich Text cell {0}: bold text: [{1}]", i, element.Text.Trim());
            }
        }
        else {
            if (cell.Style.Font.Bold)
                Console.WriteLine("Single-line cell {0}: bold text: [{1}]", i, cell.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Single-line cell 1: bold text: [Bold]
Rich Text cell 3: bold text: [Bold]
Rich Text cell 4: bold text: [Bold00]
Rich Text cell 4: bold text: [Bold01]
```